# How to check certificate name and alias in keystore files?

Tags: java, android, keystore

I have a bunch of .keystore files and need to find one with specific CN and alias. Is there a way to do it with keytool, jarsigner or some other tool? I found a way to check if specific keystore was used to sign a specific apk, but I also need to get the alias and certificate name in each of the files.

Answer (score 1175, accepted):

You can run the following command to list the content of your keystore file (and alias name):

```
keytool -v -list -keystore /path/to/keystore
```

If you are looking for a specific alias (for example foo), you can also specify it in the command:

```
keytool -list -keystore /path/to/keystore -alias foo
```

If the alias is not found, it will display an exception:

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias  does not exist

Comment: Hi can I display the key alias password If I know the key alias name and have keystore certificate and keystore password

Comment: @prateek You can't. There wouldn't be much point in having keystore or key passwords if you could just display then with a command-line tool.

Comment: You can run the following command to list the content of your keystore file:

keytool -list -keystore .keystore
The above commond is not providing the name of alias

Comment: @ManmohanSoni I have updated it to include -v argument which reveals the alias

Comment: I think that `/path/to/keystore` instead of `.keystore` would be more clear to the reader. Anyway it is the correct answer!

Comment: Even if we don't enter password the command will show the content (despite of setting a password for keystore file)! Why???

Comment: @VahidShir It doesn't show all the content unless you provide the password. Only the non-secret stuff.

Comment: In answer to @Prateek if you used a GUI and entered only a keystore pass, the alias pass will be the same. Just come unstuck myself as a Xamarin user.

Answer (score 314):

In order to get all the details I had to add the -v option to romaintaz answer:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore <FileName>.keystore
```

Comment: keytool -v -list -keystore <FileName>.jks

Comment: keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts

Comment: "If the `-v` option is specified, then the certificate is printed in **human-readable format**, with additional information such as the owner, issuer, serial number, and any extensions." (see: [Java SE Tools Reference, Display Data command, -list option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_list))

Answer (score 84):

You can run from Java code.

```
try {

        File file = new File(keystore location);
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        String password = "password";
        keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());


        Enumeration<String> enumeration = keystore.aliases();
        while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println("alias name: " + alias);
            Certificate certificate = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
            System.out.println(certificate.toString());

        }

    } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(null != is)
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Certificate class holds all information about the keystore.

**UPDATE- OBTAIN PRIVATE KEY**

```
Key key = keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
String encodedKey = new Base64Encoder().encode(key.getEncoded());
System.out.println("key ? " + encodedKey);
```

@prateek Hope this is what you looking for!

Comment: import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

Comment: @Renjith hello This code displays everything except the password associated with alias, How can I display it . Please help  me

Comment: @Renjith `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException` this is the exception thrown when I try this code actualy I want to retrieve alias password

Comment: you should use the code snippet inside the aforementioned while loop

Comment: I didnt have Base64Encoder class. Can you please tell me which jar file does it have? or is it a .java file?

Comment: So if i add a certificate into a Keystore, then i automatically get an alias?

Comment: This was a life saver for me.  Comodo in their wisdom created an alias that showed up with a ? in middle. Like "mycompany's comodo id" .  That ? turned out to be some kind of quote which does not show up on on my keyboard.  I had to copy and paste the quote from the java output, and used that with keytool to make the alias something more usable.

Answer (score 65):

[KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net)  open source visual tool to manage keystores.

Comment: This is close to a link-only answer. The policy is that you should post some information on how to use the tool/library in the answer itself.

Comment: dead link, this is why link only answer is terrible

Answer (score 28):

In a bash-like environment you can use:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts.jks | grep 'Alias name:' | grep -i foo
```

This command consist of 3 parts. As stated above, the **1st** part will list all trusted certificates with all the details and that's why the **2nd** part comes to filter only the alias information among those details. And finally in the **3rd** part you can search for a specific alias (or part of it). The *-i* turns the case insensitive mode on. Thus the given command will yield all aliases containing the pattern 'foo', f.e. foo, 123_FOO, fooBar, etc. For more information `man grep`.

Answer (score 23):

This will list all certificates:

```
keytool -list -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
```

Comment: This will only list certificates stored in the JDK's trust store which is similar but for a different purpose to a keystore (which was asked about). There is a good differentiation here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935619/what-is-difference-between-cacerts-and-keystore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935619/what-is-difference-between-cacerts-and-keystore).

Comment: Passoword: changeit (default)

Answer (score 10):

**cmd:**

```
keytool -list -keystore 'keystoreName'
```

and then press 'Enter'
the cmd will then prompt you to enter the keystore password

cmd doesn't show the password on the screen while typing
so just type the correct passwd -and be careful- then press enter again.

**Or** You can use:

```
keytool -list -keystore 'keystoreName' -storepass 'type your keystore passwd'
```

**and for Keys' full info, just add -v:**

```
keytool -v -list -keystore 'keystoreName' -storepass 'type your keystore passwd'
```

Answer (score 6):

On Windows:

**keytool -v -list -keystore *my_keystore* | findstr *my_string***

Reference:

[CMD Search a directory to Find a string inside a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537643/cmd-search-a-directory-to-find-a-string-inside-a-file)

Answer (score 3):

we can get the list of Certificates from Certs with simple command and search for your alias name in the resulted output.

```
keytool -list -keystore C:/swdtools/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Answer (score 2):

There are also console certificate manager written as a single-file shell script (open-source):

https://dev.to/sfkulyk/writing-panel-manager-for-certificate-keystore-in-linux-shell-187b

Can browse, copy, delete, rename and compare keystores.

Comment: OMG! This is a masterpiece! Tremendous!

Answer (score 2):

If you get a warning

`Warning: use -cacerts option to access cacerts keystore`

then you may use this command

`.\keytool.exe -list -cacerts`

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.but it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> keytool -v -list -cacerts -alias cert1

This worked for me when I am checking for the certificate added to jdk-11 with alias name and check if it was added on windows machine