# Microservice: consul couldn't check health of service when enabling https

Tags: spring-cloud, service-discovery, consul

I'm trying to  use Consul in microservice application based on Spring cloud.
But when I enable HTTPS in tomcat server, consul couldn't check health of service (because they try  to check the health with http). I got this error:

```
 ani got this error: gent: http request failed 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.dsk.eur.msd.world.xxxxxx:1235/health'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.scheme=https`.

Comment: With this config, Consul check health using https. but now the cerificate is not recognized xxxx.eur.msd.xxx.xxxxxxx:1234/health': Get https://xxxxxxxx.xxxx:1234/health: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Comment: I think that is now a consul issue.

Comment: This might be more related to the missing CA entry in the Java truststore. The trust store is the "file" where Java stores it's CA info. Here is a link to the manual part of Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablqw/index.html and a SO article, that explains the difference between the trust and keystore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935619/what-is-difference-between-cacerts-and-keystore