# Signed with a different certificate error but they are using the same keystore

Tags: android

So I had a client come in and give me an app to make a small modification to. However, after i made the modifications and then signed it, using the keystore of the previous developer, it won't upload to the market.

`You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s): It then goes to show that the  SHA1 are different`

Can I not update the app when I have the keystore?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are NOT using the same keystore.  You can check this pretty easily using the keystore tool.

Check this SO question: [How to check certificate name and alias in keystore files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893995/how-to-check-certificate-name-and-alias-in-keystore-files)

There is NO way to update an existing app if the signing certificate doesn't match the original (there is NO way to workaround this)

Comment: Are SHA1 specific to each keystore or each developer's PC?

Comment: No, you can sign using the same keystore from ANY computer.  My suspicion is that you DON'T have the correct keystore like you think you do.

Comment: That could be the problem. I guess we won't know for sure. All I do know is that we have a keystore with an alias and password and everything seems to work just fine but the SHA1 are different when we upload it... I guess we will just have to say its not right since we have no access to the previous developer.

Comment: You CAN confirm the current certificate information (look at my original answer).

Comment: @Bogger I did the list and the alias list and all it gives is the MD5 not the SHA1

Comment: @Bogger I was able to use the -v to get the SHA1 and its different that the one the app is signing it with when I export.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to upload when you have a matching keystore and matching password.  If you were trying to upload an application with a different keystore than the original is when you would come into issues.

If the original is lost, then there is no way to update an existing one.  You would have to remove the old application and load another one onto the Play Store.  Which of course would disrupt current users and cause confusion.  As far as I recall that is the resolution in the secondary case.

Comment: @jcaruso I have signed and loaded updates from different computers.  If you are passing around the keystore, and you input the correct password, then all should work out just fine.