# CMD Search a directory to Find a string inside a file

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I need to find the files in a directory that have specific strings, using Windows CMD prompt.

E.g., I need to find the files that have a string like this:

```
<h1>Select an Item</h1>
```

Answer (score 14):

"findstr" iswhat you are looking for.

```
findstr /I "<h1>Select\ an\ Item</h1>" *.*
```

`findstr` is the command, `/I` is a flag to match the string case insensitive. `"<h1>Select\ an\ Item</h1>"` is your string (note the escaped spaces!) and `*.*` means "in all files in this directory".

The basic syntax is `findstr "seachString" filename.ext`.
You may replace `filename.ext` with `*.ext` or `*.*` to filter cretin file types or look in all files.
This will look only in the current directory and not recursively.

More information about the command [findstr documentation](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Comment: just add /S if you want results for subfolders as well

Answer (score 4):

The command you require is fundamentally `findstr`.

type

```
findstr /?
```

at the prompt for directions.

The command that may work for you is

```
findstr /m /g:"a file containing your string or strings" *
```

or

```
findstr /m /L /c:"<h1>Select an Item</h1>" *
```

Where some experimentation with the contents of the `"quoted string"` may be required, especially wrt characters line `<>()` and others with a particular meaning to `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open up a Windows console (or CMD).
2. Go to the folder, from where you want to start the search.
3. Let's say you search for a text (e. g. "abc") in a folder, specifically in all the Word files (e. g. ".doc" and "docx"). Then the command should look like this

> ```
> findstr /s /i /m /c:"abc" *.docx *.doc
> ```

You will get a list with all the Word documents, that contain the text, including the the subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

Find some string inside all text files in current directory:

```
cls & for %i in (*.txt) do find /i "search text" < "%i" && (echo : %i & echo -)
```

Tested in Win 10