# Eclipse keystore in android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, keystore

**So, here is my problem** : 8 months ago I developped an app android and I published it on the play store. Meanwhile I changed my pc (cause of it was broke) so now I decided to create an update to the app, I developped it on Android studio (and it's work) but now the problem is I don't know how to sign correctly the app (I'm enter the same informations that I put in eclipse 8months ago : alias, password, etc)  but when I upload it on the playstore console It doesn't work (the sha1 key doesn't match). So do you have any solution to my probleme ?

ps: I think I found the keystore but there is no extention to the file, and when I import it to android studio it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you will need a previously uploaded apk. You can find the apk's SHA following these instructions:
[How do I find out which keystore was used to sign an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-to-find-out-which-key-was-used-to-sign-an-app)

You say that you found a keystore that can be the one that you used to sign your old versions of the apk. To ensure that, you need to find your keystore SHA. To do this, follow these instructions:
[How to check certificate name and alias in keystore files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893995/how-to-check-certificate-name-and-alias-in-keystore-files)

If both SHAs are the same, you found the correct keystore file (don't worry about the file extension), so you will be able to sign your app's new version with the keystore file you found. You can do this on Android Studio following these instructions:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Thank you so much, i found the key that was used :) . i followd your clear information. It works :) I just sent my update to the play store. Thanks :D