# Signing android App Keystore info?

Tags: android, keystore

I recently had a hard drive crash and I lost many files
I have android app on google play which I used to sign using a keystore file which was generated using eclipse.

I have managed to recover the keystore file and I remember one password that relates to it.

I do not remember what what alias, OU etc values were used.

So the question is

1: Is the keystore file alone with one password enough to sign updates to the existing apps or is there something else that I should try to retrieve from my dying hard disk ?

2: How can I know if my password that I remember is valid for the keystore ?

Please advise.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893995/how-to-check-certificate-name-and-alias-in-keystore-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893995/how-to-check-certificate-name-and-alias-in-keystore-files)

Comment: OK i have used this tool it asks for a password when I give it the password it says your key-store contains one entry. so the question remains is there anything else I need to be able to sign the app and publish updates, as I said I do not remember the information that I provided in other fields such as Organization alias etc at the time of filling form to create this key store.

Comment: In the future you should switch to Android Studio. [Then you can manage it in your project so you don't have to remember the passwords.](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)