# Keystore file exists but is empty?

Tags: android, android-studio, sha1, keytool, signed-apk

I need the SHA 1 fingerprint from my RELEASE key and as I understand the key is generated when I select the option in Android Studio to build a signed release APK and then I get a Keystore.jks file.By following the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) I did this command `keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>`, but this gave me 
`illegal options:/` error so I looked around the net and did this `keytool -exportcert -alias freenthrowkey -keystore C:\Users\User\Documents\FreeNthrowkey`

and this now gives me this error: `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty: C:\Users\User\Documents\FreeNthrowkey`

Please if anyone could help me out I would REALLY appreciate it.

Comment: this might be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12894334/2571277

Comment: I downloaded the program and it showed me the key and the fingerprint :D, but my google sign in still isnt working , but atleast it solved me this problem. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using following commands should give you proper output:

```
keytool -list -keystore .keystore
```

If you are looking for a specific alias, you can also specify it in the command:

```
keytool -list -keystore .keystore -alias foo
```

Also, to generate signed APK I suggest you to use Android studio itself. Choose "Generate Signed APK" from Build menu of Android studio and follow the steps. It will generate proper `keystore` at given path.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I had exectly the same problem. Issue appear when you give path to keystore file without the file name. You have to give keystore file name with the path after -keystore option. This means in your case:

`keytool -exportcert -alias freenthrowkey -keystore C:\Users\User\Documents\FreeNthrowkey\KEYSTOREFILENAME.jks`

Comment: This solved it! The problem was the missing keystore file name!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows check the following path
%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore

It might be already generated previously