# Kafka connection with pem from jks

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, pem, jks

now i have two jks file: `kafka.client.truststore.jks` and `client.keystore.jks`, however, python connection libs all using pem file auth way. So i try to convert this two file into pem by this post: [Connect to Apache Kafka from Python using SSL](http://maximilianchrist.com/blog/connect-to-apache-kafka-from-python-using-ssl)，and found these exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/luke/Code/python/mykafka/mykafka.py", line 10, in <module>
  ssl_keyfile='/Users/luke/Code/java/kafka-keys/key.pem')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 328, in __init__
  **self.config)
... ...
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 633, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
```

i received this two jks file from others, so i don't know what the alias for these jks file, so i follow this qa: [How to check certificate name and alias in keystore files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893995/how-to-check-certificate-name-and-alias-in-keystore-files) to list all the alias and found only one, so use it in the post way.

my command to create pem is flollwing:

```
keytool -list -keystore .keystore

keytool -exportcert -alias kafka-client -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -rfc -file certificate.pem

keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -srcalias kafka-  client -destkeystore cert_and_key.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
openssl pkcs12 -in cert_and_key.p12 -nocerts -nodes

keytool -exportcert -alias ca -keystore kafka.client.truststore.jks -rfc -file CARoot.pem
```

i wonder what's wrong, i try these two jks file in java, they work well.