# Can we fully change android source code in App Update?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

We want to update our published app in google play. But I want to confirm can we fully change android source code expect package name. We have our .jks reserved and we want to update graphics in app not App Icon. We forget our signed key details. Can we again rebuilt signed details with existing .jks file. Please suggest.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: yes, you can change source code, but not package name. About keystore, you can get name and alias. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893995 You can rebuild app with existing keystore.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "We forget our signed key details"? You need to use the exact same signature key to do an update.

Comment: @Henry If it is must to use same signature key for next update then we want to know how to extract our existing signature key. OR if it not must then can we generate new signature for our next apk update in google play.

Comment: Does that mean you still have the signature key but you don't know which one was used?

Comment: we missed our signature key dear. @Henry

Comment: Then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lost your signature key, then you can't update your app. This is why Google Play introduced [Google Play signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?). Google signs the app for you, takes care of the keys, and if you lose your they can migrate you to a new upload key.

If you aren't using Google Play App signing there is nothing you can do - the android system requires you to sign an update with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the the entire source code. All you need to [Update your app](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) is :

> Use the following checklist to make sure your new APK is ready to
>   update your existing users:
>
> 1. The package name of the updated APK needs to be the same as the
>      current version.
> 2. The version code needs to be greater than that
>      current version. [Learn more about versioning your applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html).
> 3. The updated APK needs to be signed with the same signature as the
>      current version.

---

As general practice you can install one of the old APKs generate a new signed and install it. If it installs without any issue you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can change the source code but remember following things before update :

keystore (same that used to build app)
Check backward compatibility
Don't change package name
update version number (like previous 1.0 update to 2.0 or 1.1 something)