# Can a native Android app in PlayStore be replaced with a KMP app?

Tags: android, google-play, kotlin-multiplatform

Can one replace a native Android app by an KMP app in the PlayStore? I am asking because of things like SHA1 hashes for Firebase etc, can those simply be updated?

Comment: Related: [Can we fully change android source code in App Update?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48636357/295004) but there will never be a canonical answer as it is a policy issue with Google Play Store and [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/295004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can if package name and key is same