# Retrive SHA256 from Signed Keystore in Android App Programatically

Tags: android, android-keystore, jks

I have signed application with keystore with JKS extension. I am using **KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")** but it is giving exception **java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found**
the purpose of loading this is that I am storing my key information in this keystore like hash etc and will use this hash to encrypt things
I have store keys using **keytool from command line** but how to retrieve?

**EDIT**

I want to do it programmatically not from command line. I want to retrieve alias and keystore in code not command line

Comment: Does you only need the keystore alias or you should need to use withing the app for any other purpose?

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal: I want to use that in the app also. I will use the alias to get the hash and then decrypt my in app items which i have encrypted using the hash stored in the keystore

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12894711/1515052

Comment: @Simulant: the link you have mentioned is expecting the keystore to be in assets or storage location but i want read keystore(used to sign apk) sha, certificate etc.