# Update an Android package, problem with the signing process

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

I'm trying to update some changes I made to an Ionic app following [these steps](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html), the problem I have is I didn't develop the app in the first place. I'm just the new guy here and in that tutorial when I have to execute `$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name` I always get one of the two following errors:

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: ****.  **** must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
```

I'm a little lost here , I don't understand what's the alias name (the tutorial doesn't explain this), also my boss only gave me the password and the keystore file, but he didn't give me the `alias_name` (although I have asked him this many times), should I keep asking him the `alias_name`? I mean, is this completely necessary?

Comment: alias_name is required to sign, also the Keystore created must align with the alias_name it was created with. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893995/how-to-check-certificate-name-and-alias-in-keystore-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

A keystore have a password, and inside it have pairs of alias/passwords, you have to know all three of those to reuse a keystore, ask the old developers.

Comment: In addition, if anyone face the same problem as me you can `keytool -v -list -keystore keystore_file_name` and get the alias.