# How we change key store alias

Tags: android, keystore, jar-signing

I have JKS keystore and I remember the password but not alias.

It's said 'No key found with the alias'.

please help.

Comment: open the jks file by double clicking it and you will find your alias in it

Comment: See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893995/how-to-check-certificate-name-and-alias-in-keystore-files#29698543

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio, then you can find the key alias like this if you know the password,

Enter your keystore path and password, and tap on the folder icon at key alias section,

[image]

You will get the key alias list in new window like this,

[image]

You can use existing key, or if you want, you can create new one.

Comment: wwwwwooooooooooowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww thanks buddy it worked. I never noticed that 'browse' button for alias edittext.

Comment: I'm glad to helped you buddy :)