# There's any way to read SHA1 jks key?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I'm updating a couple of apps to upload to Play Store but doesn't know which one belong to what app and there's like 15 .jks files and when try to upload the signed APK the Store doesn't like the signature and tell me to use the one with an specific code but I don't know how to know which one has that code inside.

Comment: please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12894334/13116405) in case you want to see the content of your keystore including sha1 and you can decompile the signed apk to compare sha1 also in future make sure to name your keys in a proper way to differentiate between them

Comment: I'm not the original developer, he's in another country and doesn't work anymore. He left us a mess, all the keys has the same name.